# Interpret Windows Native API call arguments

Tags: winapi, kernel, kernel32, ntdll, nt-native-api

I am analyzing an executable based on its execution trace. I have obtained the execution trace using [NtTrace](http://www.howzatt.demon.co.uk/NtTrace/) tool. The output is a sequence of native api calls with arguments. I have managed to interpret most of the API calls except the following ones:

```
NtQueryKey( KeyHandle=0x46a, KeyInformationClass=7 [KeyHandleTagsInformation], KeyInformation=0x312c4e0, Length=4, ResultLength=0x312c4dc [4] ) => 0

NtDeviceIoControlFile( FileHandle=0xbe4, Event=0xce8, ApcRoutine=null, ApcContext=null, IoStatusBlock=0x124cf2b0 [0/0xffc], IoControlCode=0x00012017, InputBuffer=0x124cf298, InputBufferLength=0x10, OutputBuffer=null, OutputBufferLength=0 ) => 0
```

In `NtQueryKey`, how can I map the `KeyHandle=0x46a` to an actual registry key. Further, in `NtDeviceIoControlFile` based on `IoControlCode=0x00012017` is it possible to find whether it is a TCP_RECV, TCP_SEND, etc...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Process Monitor from Sysinternals (now part of Microsoft) will show you the actual key path when displaying registry activity.  It also can monitor network activity.

[Sysinternals Tools](http://sysinternals.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just look back in the trace to find the point at which that key handled was opened.  You may have to repeat this process recursively if the key was opened relative to another key.  In the future, I recommend using procmon from sysinternals.  The output is much better.